# what it gets called method overriding? or duplicating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, overloading, overriding

Senario 1:

```
updateQuery = (query) => {
   this.setState({query: query.trim()})
 }

    updateQuery = (query) => {
   this.setState({query: query.splice()})
 }
```

Senario 2:

```
clearQuery() {
   this.setState({ query : ‘’})
 }

    clearQuery() {
   this.setState({ query : ‘veeru’})
 }
```

here are two Scenarios for #1 we are overriding the `updateQuery` value and for #2 we have two methods with the same name `clearQuery` only method body is different, in this case, what it gets called method overriding? or duplicating?

Comment: Javascript does not support function overloading

Comment: How is React.js involved?

Comment: last one will overwrite the previous one.

Comment: In .Net this would be called method overloading but JS doesn't allow it. Your function gets redefined and the last one is the only one that exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch this test:

```
let test = () => {
  console.log('first');
};

test = () => {
  console.log('second');
};

test = () => {
  console.log('last');
};


test();
```

The result:
`last`

As you can see, the last function overwrites the previous.